# Extract text between two pattern in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to extract out all texts **including** categories (i.e. A, B, C).

```
A     <some text1> 

B     <some text2> 

C     <some text3>
```

However, when I apply this regex -

```
ptrn='\n[A-z]*\t'     

pattern1= '(.*)'+ptrn      

f = re.findall(pattern1,test_doc)
```

it gives me

```
f[0] = A     <some text1> 

f[1] = <some text2> 

f[2] = <some text3>
```

But I want -

```
f[0] =  A     <some text1>

f[0] =  B     <some text2> 

f[2] =  C     <some text2>
```

http://csmining.org/tl_files/Project_Datasets/r8%20r52/r8-test-all-terms.txt

this link has some raw text of many documents.
each document has following pattern:

```
category<tab><sometext> \n
```

hence the whole corpus looks like this:-

```
category<tab><sometext1> \n 

category<tab><sometext2> \n

.

.
```

i want

```
doc[0] = category<tab><sometext1>

doc[1] = category<tab><sometext2>

.
.
and so on
```

Any answer/hint will be very helpful :)

Comment: Wait so you want to find all the text? Why do you need regex? Is there other text somewhere that you don't want?

Comment: Why not just use `s.split('\n')`?

Comment: @EvanNowak because <some text> can contain '\n' and it will split within <some text> .

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/no7v8p/1), but it's hard to tell. Can you give us a more specific example input/output?

Comment: http://csmining.org/tl_files/Project_Datasets/r8%20r52/r8-test-all-terms.txt

this link has some raw text of many documents.
each document has following pattern:

category<tab><sometext1> \n
category<tab><sometext2> \n
.
.

i want doc[1] = category<tab><sometext1>
doc[2] = category<tab><sometext2>
and so on

Comment: I updated question too...please look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
import re
pattern = r"(\w+)(\t)(.*)(\b)"
```

**Explanation**

- `(\w+)` matches any word character, one or many times
- `\t` matches the tab character literally
- `(.*)` matches everything except line terminators
- `(\b)` is a word boundary

[See a demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/no7v8p/2/)